# Why Eclipse folding shortcuts are not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee-8

I was trying to get better control over my code by using eclipse folding shortcuts. Trouble is none of the shortcuts that I found were working even though they are bound to collapse and expand code in the eclipse keys section. I have folding enabled and I also have codeMix plugin installed. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!
[key shortcuts commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMeuT.png)

Comment: Louay, mind sharing what version of Eclipse you are using and what language / editor you are working in? Does it fail even for Java for instance? The shortcuts seemed to work fine when we tested them.

Comment: eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64. Am using it for java coding. I just tried the folding shortcuts on an XML editor and to my surprise, it worked. I went back to the java class I was editing but it didn't work. Then I opened other java classes from another project and this time it worked. So when I reopened the actual class I was working on the shortcuts finally folded the code properly. I just want to mention that before today I tried the code folding shortcuts on all Eclipse editors and none of them worked. I suspect that the **codeMix** plugin made some kind of conflict in the IDE.